# Html card: Image cannot be smaller

Tags: html, css

I am making card design in cakephp, 
but when it comes to show longer image than 600px width,

It extended insanely!!!

I am using placeholder or dummyimage but it has no problem.

Why this is happening? What should I do to show smaller images?

html inline width height constraint did not work.

```
<div class="cards">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x150/000/fff" >
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: 300x300img]
[image]

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.cards {
    width: 30%;
    background: #999;
}
.image img {
   width: 100%; 
}
.title {
    text-align: center;
}
.des {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set your image to take 100% of the container size, which is 30% of the screen width. Set

```
.image img {
   width: auto; 
}
```

Important, if your screen is too small, then the background will only cover a portion of the image, since you set the `card` to be 30% of the size of the screen, but the image is being automatically sized. Try adding `max-width: 100%;` to the image CSS.